# How I can implements method from one class in another class

Tags: java

I have class `Shape2D`, in that class I have method that calculate circle area `circleArea`, also I have class `CircleArea` where I store all atributes that I need for my method. Also, my class `CircleArea` extends class `Shape2D`. So, How I can implement my method from class `Shape2D` into class `CircleArea`.

This is my `Shape2D` class:

```
public class Shape2D {
    public static void areaCircle(Circle c) {
        double circleArea = Math.pow(c.getR(), 2) * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

And this is my `Circle` class:

```
public class Circle extends Shape2D {

    private double r;

    public Circle() {
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

}
```

Comment: Google "method overriding". Also, please read "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)".

Comment: Oh thank you, I will. I searched the wrong keyword.

Comment: where is the so often mentioned `CircleArea` class - or did you meant `Circle`? (and the whole design is a bit strange; a `Shape2D` should not know how to calculate an area, IMO)

Answer (score 0):

To implement one of the methods from the `Shape2D` class in the `Circle` class, you could do:

```
Shape2D.areaCircle(circleObject);
```

The above line can be called in the `Circle` class. Don't forget to pass  in an actual `circle` object into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have a static method inside of 2D shape, meaning you can use it in any class without having 2DShape instantiated. This also means that you do not need the circle class to extend 2DShape to use this method, but I imagine you are going for that parent child relationship for the OO paradigm. If you don't want the method to be called from any class, remove `static` from the method. If you wish to call it statically inside of your Circle class constructor, first instantiate r to something, and then pass it into the static method call.

```
public class Circle extends Shape2D {

    private double r;

    public Circle() {
         r=1;
         Shape2D.areaCircle(this);
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

}
```

**Note that your static function doesn't actually return anything, so it calculates the area and the value is lost.** You can fix this inside of shape2D by changing the return type of `circleArea` to double in stead of void, and returning the result appropriately.

```
public static double areaCircle(Circle c) {
        double circleArea = Math.pow(c.getR(), 2) * Math.PI;
        return circleArea;
    }
```

or non-statically, and protected in stead of public (either will work)

```
protected double areaCircle(Circle c) {
        double circleArea = Math.pow(c.getR(), 2) * Math.PI;
        return cricleArea;
    }
```

If you wanted to do the same thing, but removed the static flag from the method, then you can use `super` to call parent methods.

```
public class Circle extends Shape2D {

    private double r;

    public Circle() {
         r=1;
         super.areaCircle(this);
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

}
```

Now if you wanted to actually store the area inside of this circleObject, I would create another attribute for the Circle class, and modify your constructor as such. Perhaps even adding a constructor that takes an int argument for radius (or in the future, an area with some way to differentiate the two that can get the radius value).

```
public class Circle extends Shape2D {

    private double r;
    private double area;
    //Default Constructor
    public Circle() {
         r=1;
         this.area = super.areaCircle(this);
    }
    //Radius constructor
    public Circle(double rad) {
        this.r = rad;
        this.area = super.areaCircle(this);
    }
    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

}
```

It's also worth mentioning that you should look at the scope of these methods you create, and what you are trying to accomplish with them. For instance, you have your `circleArea` method defined as public, when it could be defined as protected and function similarly for this case. Protected means that the method can be used inside of the class, as well as all subclasses (children of the parent class, like circle). You can read information about these closures [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/difference-between-private-protected-public-package-access-java.html). Also, when working with object inheritance, you should get into the habit of using the `this` keyword to reference which methods/attributes you actually wish to retrieve. [Info on this keyword](https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/this-keyword-java/).

I realize this is a lot to take in, but if you have any questions feel free to comment!